# Export import sql database without downloading

Tags: mysql, sql

Recently i need to change my server to another webhosting providers server. To do that just discovered that my MySQL database size is too much to download & upload with the access that I have.

Using phpMyAdmin, can I export from my current MySQL server and directly import to my new MySQL server so that I do not have to download the data?

Comment: I assume you are using MySQL considering the use of PHPMyAdmin?

Comment: yes, thats MySQL

Comment: I am not aware of a way to do this with phpMyAdmin  - but I do not use that tool very often.  You will be best served if you can get shell access.  If your database is large, I've seen issues with MyAdmin timeouts.

Comment: that's good idea....

Comment: If you can get shell access, see the trick below to export/import at once between two servers.

Answer (score 1):

Your phrase "access that I have." is interesting.  Are you bandwidth limited?  Space limited?  Shell limited?  Explaining that would help clarify a better suited solution to your particular parameters.

In order to get the DB from one machine to the other your *have* to transfer the files.  you could do this several different ways:

1.) Copy the whole mysql directory (after stopping mysql of course)

rsync -a main_host:/var/lib/mysql/ smaecond_host:/var/lib/mysql/

2.) Use mysqldump to dump the data base to a file then transfer said file:

On the main sever:

```
mysqldump > [local_file]
rsync [local_file] secondary:host
```

On the new server:

```
mysql < [local_file]
```

3.) Sneakernet may be an option if you have physical access to one or both

If you are bandwidth limited rsync can be given the --bwlimit switch to rate-limit a xfer.  If you are  space limited - then you may have a much larger problem.

Answer (score 0):

This does not use phpMyAdmin, so may not apply to your case.

If using MySQL and you have shell access, consider using mysqldump with pipes.

http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/mysqldump-pipe-mysql-output-and-input/

Note this can lock tables on both servers.  Also if you do not use SSH the data is sent as plain text.  I have often used this method over fast, private network links.